# EJB 3.1 Application Design

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, ejb, javabeans

I am developing an application, for a very simple Student Resource Management System (SRMS)

I am supposed to use Enterprise Java Beans, a stand alone Java GUI client, and a web browser client

If I use `Servlets` for the browser client, should I put all my logic in the enterprise beans, and just call the methods from the `Servlet`? so I could call the same kind of methods from the standalone GUI application as well.

What is confusing is that I should not have any logic in my `Servlets`, I should have all my logic in the beans tier of the application.

One more thing: What is the difference between a `Session Bean` and an `Session Bean from Entity Classes`?

The GUI client will also use login, but that is the only similar action which will be used by the browser client as well. The browser client can only search and view some data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your business logic in EJB session beans which in turn use EJB JPA entities to access a database for example. If all of your logic has to reside in the EJB tier, you have to go this way. So the EJB session beans are the interfaces to your business logic. JPA entity classes are mapped onto tables in an RDBMs.

This way servlets and stand-alone command-line applications can call the methods defined in the EJB session beans. The session beans should return data transfer objects which are ready to be shown in the view (= no further processing in the servlet for example).

As a rule of thumb, try to limit yourself to calling only one EJB method, if the user clicks on a "Search" button for example. Otherwise there might be too much traffic, especially for the command-line application, as that one is normally not run on the same host. So pay attention on the design of the EJB session bean interfaces.

EJB session beans are managed beans (controlled by an application server), and provide declarative transactions/security for example.

EJB entity beans have been deprecated, and have been replaced with JPA.

Comment: Hej thank you that is a great answer. But still in Nebeans you have the option to create `Session Bean For Entity Classes` and is used in Netbeans tutorial about Java EE 6. The no-view session beans, do it means it does not need an interface at all?

Comment: That probably means "EJB session beans" with "EJB JPA entities" (that's what I have described in the first paragraph). "EJB JPA entities" have replaced "EJB entity beans": [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Entity_beans_.28deprecated.29)

Comment: For some reason me trying to access an entity facade through a normal session bean, is not working. I am trying to access the database to get some users, but it does not work. But it works when I do the same from a servlet

Comment: Please post another question regarding this problem - that's no longer design, that's already implemenetation :-)